# Is substitution implemented in the Haskell backend?

Tags: kframework

I've been using the Java backend for symbolic execution because it has substitution (e.g. `E[V/X]`). Is substitution implemented in the Haskell backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of July 2020, the answer is no.

Comment: Are there any plans to implement it? if not, is it possible to define a substitution function that makes use of the `binder` tags?

Comment: Yes, it's on the list of things we plan to implement eventually. Right now the Haskell backend team is focused on other things, however. I can't give an estimate of when we may end up working on it.

Comment: out of curiosity, is it standard then to implement your own substitution function when using the Haskell backend?

Comment: No, it's just that all the languages that the haskell backend has been tried on to date were either not functional, or used environments instead of substitution